# problems with timestamp and concurrency

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, concurrency, timestamp

I am using EF 4.0 and I have in my database a table with a timestamp field because I want to control the concurrency in this table.

Then, I created my edmx and I generated the POCO classes with the template DBContext.

The first try that I do is, in the edmx, in the timestamp field, I set stored generated pattern to none. Then in my code I do:

```
myContext.MyTable.Attach(myEntity);
myContext.Entry<MyTable>(myEntity).Property(p => p.AnyFieldNoTimestamp).IsModified = true;
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

This give me an exception that says that is not possible to update a timestamp column.

If I have I only marked a field to modified, and this field is not the timestamp, why I get this error?

Then I try to set the propery stored generated pattern in the edmx to Indentity.

really I have a transaction and two saveChanges. In this second try, the  first savechanges does not give any error but in the second savechanges I get the excepcion 0 rows affected, because it seem that the timestamp of the entity has changed from the first savechanges to the second, so in the concurrency control I get this excepction.

So I would like to know how can I use a timestamp field inside a transaction and two save chages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to use the set Computed and in this case works correctly.